# Where to encrypt/decrypt my data?

Tags: encryption, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using Symfony 2 with Doctrine 2.

I need to encrypt a field in my entity using an encryption service, and I'm wondering where should I put this logic.

I'm using a Controller > Service > Repository architecture.

I was wondering if a listener would be a good idea, my main concern is, if my entity is stored encrypted, if I decrypt it on the fly its state it's gonna be changed and I'm not sure it's a good idea.

How would you implement this?

Answer (score 17):

To expand on *richsage* and *targnation*'s great answers, one way to inject a dependency (e.g., cypto service) into a custom Doctrine mapping type, could be to use a static property and setter:

```
// MyBundle/Util/Crypto/Types/EncryptedString.php
class EncryptedString extends StringType
{
    /** @var \MyBundle\Util\Crypto */
    protected static $crypto;

    public static function setCrypto(Crypto $crypto)
    {
        static::$crypto = $crypto;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $value = parent::convertToDatabaseValue($value, $platform);
        return static::$crypto->encrypt($value);
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $value = parent::convertToPHPValue($value, $platform);
        return static::$crypto->decrypt($value);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'encrypted_string';
    }
}
```

Configuration would look like this:

```
// MyBundle/MyBundle.php
class MyBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        /** @var \MyBundle\Util\Crypto $crypto */
        $crypto = $this->container->get('mybundle.util.crypto');
        EncryptedString::setCrypto($crypto);
    }
}

# app/Resources/config.yml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            encrypted_string: MyBundle\Util\Crypto\Types\EncryptedString

# MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    mybundle.util.crypto:
        class: MyBundle\Util\Crypto
        arguments: [ %key% ]
```

Answer (score 15):

I don't know if it's the right way at all, but I implemented this recently by creating a [custom mapping type](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/basic-mapping.html#custom-mapping-types), as per the Doctrine docs. Something like the following:

```
class EncryptedStringType extends TextType
{
    const MYTYPE = 'encryptedstring'; // modify to match your type name

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return base64_decode($value);
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return base64_encode($value);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::MYTYPE;
    }
}
```

I registered this type in my bundle class:

```
class MyOwnBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function boot()
    {
        $em = $this->container->get("doctrine.orm.entity_manager");
        try
        {
            Type::addType("encryptedstring", "My\OwnBundle\Type\EncryptedStringType");

            $em->
                getConnection()->
                getDatabasePlatform()->
                registerDoctrineTypeMapping("encryptedstring", "encryptedstring");
        } catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e)
        {
            // For some reason this exception gets thrown during
            // the clearing of the cache. I didn't have time to
            // find out why :-)
        }
    }
}
```

and then I was able to reference it when creating my entities, eg:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="encryptedstring")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
protected $name;
```

This was a quick implementation, so I'd be interested to know the correct way of doing it.  I presume also that your encryption service is something available from the container; I don't know how feasible/possible it would be to pass services into custom types this way either... :-)

Comment: hi, thanks your answer, it's definitely a good idea, however I'm wondering how I could pass my private key?

Let's say I pass my EncryptionService to my Custom type using the constructor, I still need to pass it a key to use for encryption, however, as the type is used when persisting & hydrating an entity, I don't how I could do that

Comment: Yeah, in our case we used the `mcrypt_*` functions and hardcoded the iv and passphrase etc due to time constraints, but I don't know if you could eg create the type as a service and pass parameters in that way. Seems to be a lack of information as to how to do this efficiently!

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually using the mcrypt_* functions, but the key to encrypt data is generated dynamically so I can't hardcode it.

Comment: @Trent did you ever find a way to pass the encryption key to the custom type?

Comment: FWIW a static IV (shared across all encryptions) opens you up to a host of problems: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/forced-into-using-a-static-iv-aes

Comment: @MarkFox absolutely agree, +1

Answer (score 8):

*richsage's* answer was pretty good, except I wouldn't register the custom type in the bundle class file. It's recommended that you use the config.yml like so:

```
# ./app/config/confi
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        {{ etc, etc }}
        types:
            encrypted_string: MyCompany\MyBundle\Type\EncryptedStringType
```

Then just make sure in your EncryptedStringType class you specify the getName function to return encrypted_string.

Now in your model definition (or annotation) you can use the encrypted_string type.

Comment: nice, that's much cleaner :-)